# Delete Cascade not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, cascading-deletes, sqlite-net-extensions

I have two tables in my database, one for recipes and one for their ingredients. When a particular recipe is deleted, I want all its ingredients gone as well. I have declared a one to many relationship with cascade attribute set but when I delete some recipe it does not delete the relevant ingredients.

Here are my tables:

```
    public class Recipe_Model
    {

        [PrimaryKey AutoIncrement]
        public int RecipeID { get; set; }
        public string RecipeName { get; set; }
        public double RecipeCost { get; set; }
        public double ServingsNo { get; set; }
        public double CostPercent { get; set; }
        public double SellingPrice { get; set; }
        public double CostPerServing { get; set; }

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]      // One to many relationship with Ingredients
        public ObservableCollection<Ingredients_Model> Ingredients { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ingredients_Model
    {
        [PrimaryKey AutoIncrement]
        public int IngredientID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Recipe_Model))]
        public int RecipeID { get; set; }

        public string IngredientName { get; set; }
        public string UsedUnit { get; set; }
        public string PurchasedUnit { get; set; }
        public double QuantityUsed { get; set; }
        public double QuantityPurchased { get; set; }
        public double PurchasePrice { get; set; }
        public double IngredientCost { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my delete operation:

```
    public void DeleteRecipe()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection())
        {
            var recipe = database.Get<Recipe_Model>(RecipeID);
            database.Delete(recipe, true);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascade operations only work for objects in memory. In your specific scenario, you are obtaining a single object from database via `Get` method and the cascade operations will delete all in-memory relationships, which is currently nothing because `Ingredients` property is `null`.

If you don't already have the objects in memory, it doesn't make sense to load them just to get the identifiers to delete them, which is exactly what cascade deletion do:

```
// This would work as it loads children to memory, but it's inefficient
var recipe = database.GetWithChildren<Recipe_Model>(RecipeID);
database.Delete(recipe, true);
```

Instead, I'd recommend you to delete them manually:

```
database.Execute("DELETE FROM [Ingredients_Model] WHERE [RecipeID] == ?", recipe.Id);
database.Delete(recipe);
```

Comment: How would I go about deleting an object that is currently in memory? Also if I am getting this right the object that I am currently manipulating would be in memory, right? I was previously doing this: database.Delete<Recipe_Model>(RecipeID); but since it wasn't working I changed it to the Get method to try that out. Does this query also first get the object from memory?

Comment: Ah worked it out. And got all the object in memory issue! Thanks.